# Know if the content of a file has been changed using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

In my `Node.js` server, I want to know if the content of a file has been modified, and if that is true, read the content of the file and send it back via `socket.io`. My code only read the content of the file once (when the page is reloaded).

```
init = function (server_created) {
    var listen = io.listen(server_created);
    listen.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        myReadFile(socket);
    });
};

function myReadFile(socket) {
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    socket.emit('number', { number: data });
});
```

Comment: Hash the file? MD5 should be fine

Comment: could you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: Run both the old and new files through the MD5 hashing algorithm, and compare the results. There are multiple NPM packages for this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5-file

Answer (score 0):

you may need to store modification timestamp in your code and keep calling

```
fs.stat(<fileName>);
```

in `setInterval()` loop